# Connect to on-premises device through CGP app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know how to send a TCP request from Flex App engine (python application) to the on-premises device TCP port 9701 and get the data back from the device.

Option 1- Set up Cloud VPN and put the firewall hardware in front of the  on-premises existing router(if it is not VPN IPSEC supported)

Option 2- Set the on-premises router as DMZ mode with IP mapping and port forwarding.

Could anyone try it and give me some idea of how that works and using any hardware firewall that worked with the GCP VPN?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is actually very complex. I will briefly touch upon both of your options.

> Option 1- Set up Cloud VPN and put the firewall hardware in front of
>   the on-premises existing router(if it is not VPN IPSEC supported)

To set up Google Cloud VPN will require hardware routers on your side that support Google's requirements. Most cheap routers will not meet the minimum requirements.

This method is called site-to-site and you are basically connecting your internal network to your Google Cloud networks (VPCs). This requires a good understanding of VPNs and routing. The benefit is that all your traffic is secure and encrypted. Your internal systems can access your Google systems using their private IP addresses.

1. Your router must have a public static reliable IPv4 address.
2. Your internal network addressing cannot overlap with your VPCs.
3. If you put a firewall in front of your VPN router, the firewall must support passing thru ESP (IPsec) and IKE traffic.
4. Your router must support prefragmentation.
5. Dynamic routing (BGP) is preferred, Static routing is supported.

> Option 2- Set the on-premises router as DMZ mode with IP mapping and
>   port forwarding.

This method does not involve Cloud VPNs. Your side is public and your Google resources (App Engine) just access your public IP address. There is no added encryption or security in this configuration unless you add it yourself. For low-cost setups that do not require traffic security beyond HTTPS, this is OK usually. However, you have not provided your network map, services, etc to review how you should NAT/PAT and secure your traffic.

A word about DMZ. Most people assume that this is secure. It is not unless you also have an intelligent firewall in front of your DMZ. A DMZ just passes traffic blindly from port A on the public side to Port B on the private side. Many a system has been hacked because the admin thought that DMZ translated to security. Any system connected thru a DMZ should be considered high-risk to attacks and being breached.

What is the best solution? Redesign your requirements so that App Engine does not need to get into your internal network.

Comment: Hi John, thank you very much for your answer, I think to provide a software solution to small/mid-size companies, option 2 simply DMZ mod is out of the picture. Do you know any firewall hardware that will be worked with GCP? For option 1 using the cloud VPN and cloud firewall, I assumed someone travelling and wants to access the GCP, they need to use the IPSEC VPN client connects to the internet network first then access the CGP resources through the VPN tunnel? what is the benefit using the dynamic routing (cloud router needed), I try to make the set up as simple as possible. Thanks again!

Comment: @MapperkidsLee - Please create a new question after closing this question.

Comment: John, thanks and will create a new question about firewall/router recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the last answer.

If you can't bought or you don't known what HW is supported by the cloud VPN service, you can  can use a VM or onpremise server like as Firewall using [pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org/), this is freebsd distribution that have the capability to manage your network security like a NGFW and can be installed on bare metal or in a VM.

having said that, to configure site to site VPN connection between your own network and GCP network you can follow this [tutorial](http://elatov.github.io/2019/01/creating-an-ipsec-tunnel-between-google-cloud-platform-and-pfsense/#existing-documentation), this tutorial explain step by step the configuration that you need to perform in GCP and in pf sense.

Comment: Jorge, Thanks for the info, if I put another bare metal as NGFW will that affect the existing on-premises wired/wireless router? I found the VPN HW that will work with the GCP but I don't know how to hook that up with the existing on-premises router. 

Here is the model I'm think of buying: https://www.ui.com/unifi-routing/usg/

Could you take a look?